# Holder semi norm estimate for a solution of Poisson's equation in the half space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces, poissons-equation, holder-inequality

Let $u\in C^{2,\alpha}_0(\overline{\mathbb{R}^n_+})$, $0<\alpha<1$, such that

$$-\Delta u=f \quad\text{in }\quad \overline{\mathbb{R}^n_+}$$
$$ u=0 \quad\text{in }\quad \partial\overline{\mathbb{R}^n_+}$$

Then there exists a constant $C$ depending only on $N$ and $\alpha$ such that:
$$[D^2u]_\alpha\leq C[f]_\alpha$$

where $$[u]_\alpha=\sup_{x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n_+}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$$

I tried using Greens function for the halfspace and changing Morrays inequality demonstration but I'm stuck

Also, if $D^2u$ is a matrix what is the definition for $[D^2u]_\alpha$? i assumed its the maximum value of $[u_{x_ix_j}]_\alpha$ but im not sure about this.

Comment: On a pedantic note: In the title of your question you should change "half plane" to "half space" since your question concerns a problem in $\mathbb{R^n_+}$ for generic $n$. Also, you should change $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^n_+}$ in the question.

Comment: thank you! fixed

Comment: Work on a ball centered at some boundary point and use the Newtonian potential to estimate the second derivative (you will need to control a harmonic error term, but this is fine since harmonic functions satisfy pretty much any estimate of this form that you want).